# Меняется высота формы

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://coming-soon.zzz.com.ua/
Не могу понять почему меняется высота формы ввода имейла. Подскажите, я уже без сил :(  Блок называется `.maim__form`
Спасибо!

Comment: Google Chrome 52, Windows 7 - высота формы не меняется

Answer (score 2):

Измени cвойство `display` у `.main__input` с `inline-block`.

```
.main__input {
  ...
  display: block;
  ...
}
```

Либо задавайте высоту не форме, а `input`.

```
.main__input {
  ...
  height: 57px;
  ...
}
```

Иначе 100% `inline-block` - не воспринимает.

Answer (score 0):

задайт фиксированную высоту блоку с класcом `noma` и инпуту `main__input` и будет вам счатье

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?